# Refresh token in Salesforce expires in 18-24 hours

Tags: api, refresh-token

I'm running into the weirdest problem, which started appearing in June 2017, it was almost like there was some change in the Summer '17 release that is doing that. There were absolutely no changes to the app on our side and everything worked perfectly before that.

The refresh token we store and use to access Salesforce data offline started expiring after 18-24 hours, and we can't figure out why.

The Refresh token expiration policy is set to 'Never Expire' in the Connected App settings. Has anyone heard about this or knows the solution?

EDIT1: Just wanted to note that it doesn't happen for all the orgs, we've been running the app for several days on our prod and dev orgs and everything works fine. However, several customers keep complaining that their token get revoked. We specifically asked if there's a chance that an admin revoked an app manually and the answer was 'no'. It also didn't look like it when we looked at the customer's org.